# XSLT transformation adds empty <p></p> Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to adjust a set of complicated XSLT files, and I have the problem, that it is adding empty paragraph tags and I'm not sure why. I believe it has something to do with the for-each, but I don't know where these tags come from, as there are no p-Tags anywhere included in the transformation.

Is this something that xsl may add by itself when something is empty in the for-each? It is always getting directly after the for-each and and directly before the end of the for-each (effectivly surrounding the generated output).

How could I check inside the for-each if the tag is empty?

Thank you for your help.

The files are mainly of this structure:

```
// Base File
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="library.xsl" />
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

// Some keys are defined here ...

<xsl:template name="base">                  
    <xsl:call-template name="someTemplate" />
    // More templates follow ...
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The library.xsl now has the template "someTemplate" like this:

```
<xsl:template name="someTemplate">
     <xsl:for-each select="[very complicated XPath here]">
        // Some HTML generation, but absolutely withoug p-tags!!!!
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have read the thread [XSLT: How to exclude empty elements from my result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706202/xslt-how-to-exclude-empty-elements-from-my-result) and have as well tried to apply the named pattern (as my files are using for-each), but it did not work out.

Comment: Your `<p>` have to come from womewher; hard to figure out from where if you don't give us more of your source XML and XSLT templates. Another match is certainly generating them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, XSLT does not create `<p>` elements by itself. If no `<p>` element can be found in the stylesheet, or in any imported/included stylesheet, they may be copied from the source document.

It is hard to tell from the code you show. You should try to reproduce the issue with the smallest possible input file and the XSLT transformation reduced to a minimum set of rules.

Comment: Yes, I've done so. The original source does not contain any html. Thanks for your answer, if XSL does not create the <p> Tags, I'll look for other sources.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I found that it was an error in my templating engine and not XSL :)

Comment: @shredding : if the templating engine you use comes from a third-party (not a custom one), consider whether sharing what the error was could be helpfull to other users.

Comment: @AlainSaint-Etienne: The error was not related to XSL (what Eric pointed out) at all. I am using Fluid (it's an Typo3/Extbase Extension) and had to change the parseFunc of the format.html View Helper from lib.parseFunc_RTE to lib.parseFunc ...