# How to make an attribute's element not appear in a datacontract generated XML

Tags: xml, web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

We are working on AX webservices which return some datacontract (obviously).

The datacontract returned has a field (we will call him "endDate") which, sometimes, can be considering "unkwnown". Is there a way to avoid having the element corresponding to this field in the generated XML in this case.

## Exemples

**endDate known**

```
<datacontract>
    <field1>value</field1>
    <endDate>2010-10-10</endDate>
</datacontract>
```

**endDate unknwown**

```
<datacontract>
    <field1>value</field1>
</datacontract>
```

I would like to avoid having two type of datacontract, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy option is to remove the unwanted fields from the service query.

Also in the setup of the outbound port you can configure which fields to expose (under "Data policies". You cannot when configuring inbound ports.

On output AIF always emits the elements whether or not it contains data. For example:

```
</endDate>
```

if the `endData` is not set.

Comment: I wasn't clear, sorry. The datacontract returned has a field (we will call him "endDate") which, sometimes, can be considering "unkwnown". Is there a way to avoid having the element correpsonding to this field in the generated XML in this case. I will edit my question for more clarity.

Comment: So your are saying there is no way to alter this behaviour, regarding the empty fields ?

Comment: I believe not. You could try transforming the XML in a middle tier, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706202/xslt-how-to-exclude-empty-elements-from-my-result

Comment: I don't think this will work, due to the XML schema : if it is a date which is returned, the xml type is xs:date (logical) which cannot be empty (again, logical : a empty string cannot be parsed to a date). We have found a work arround in our case (if endDate before startDate, consider it Empty), but the way Ax handle XML serialization seems pretty ugly.