# Avoid empty elements in XSLT output

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to map an input XML to another XML, simply writing values from the input to different tags in the output.

As a simple example, the following:

```
<root1>
  <a1>valA<a1>
  <b1>valB<b2>
</root1>
```

Needs to become:

```
<root2>
  <a2>valA</a2>
  <b2>valB</b2>
</root2>
```

Currently I have the following in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:apply-templates match="root1" />

<xsl:template match="root1">
  <a2>
    <xsl:value-of select="a1" />
  </a2>
  <b2>
    <xsl:value-of select="b1" />
  </b2>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that I don't want empty tags in my output. If `valA` and `valB` are empty, I would get:

```
<root2>
  <a2></a2>
  <b2></b2>
<root2>
```

But I want to omit the empty tags. I would have thought that there could be an attribute to `xsl:output` for this, but there isn't... I came across this question on SO: [XSLT: How to exclude empty elements from my result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706202/1313143) - but the answer is indirect, it specifies a **second stylesheet** to strip empty output elements after the first transformation.

**I need this to be done with one stylesheet**. Surely there must be something more concise then doing:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(a1) != 0">
  <a2>
    <xsl:value-of select="a1" />
  </a2>
</xsl:if>
```

or even:

```
<xsl:template match="a1[string-length(.) != 0]">
  <a2>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </a2>
</xsl:template>
```

repeated for each element??

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts are fine in my view although instead of testing string-length many people use e.g. `<xsl:template match="a1[normalize-space()]"><a2><xsl:value-of select="."/></a2></xsl:template>` instead. But if you need to check whether an element is empty then you need some predicate or test expression, there is no setting you can switch on globally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find that this is a shortcoming of XSLT. I will not go through the daunting task of wrapping all outputs inside this expression, instead I'm going to alter the input so the tag names can be retained, after which I can use an identity transform.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to "delay" the outputting of your output.
Let me explain. By putting your output into a variable, you prevent the output from begin output and then using copy-of you can finally output the output but carefully using an XPath expression that filters the empty tags, as follows:

Let's say your source XML is:

```
<root1>
  <a1>valA</a1>
  <b1>valB</b1>
  <c1>valC</c1>
  <d1></d1>
  <e1>valE</e1>
  <f1></f1>
</root1>
```

Then you can put your output in the variable, without caring for xsl:if checks or template matches:

```
<xsl:template match="/root1">
    <xsl:variable name="output" as="node()*">
        <a1><xsl:value-of select="a1"/></a1>
        <b1><xsl:value-of select="b1"/></b1>
        <c1><xsl:value-of select="c1"/></c1>
        <d1><xsl:value-of select="d1"/></d1>
        <e1><xsl:value-of select="e1"/></e1>
        <f1><xsl:value-of select="f1"/></f1>
    </xsl:variable>

    <root1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$output[text()]"/>
    </root1>
</xsl:template>
```

Using $output[text()] allows you to keep only the tags which have a textual content.

More over, if you want to apply on all tags, you can automate a bit with a xsl:for-each loop:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="output" as="node()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <root1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$output[text()]"/>
    </root1>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a generic template that matches any 'leaf' element that has no text in it, and then just ignore such an element

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />
```

You could combine this with a template that matches just `a1`, `b1` elements without any conditions, which would do your transformation into `a2`, `b2` as currently

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root1">
    <root2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </root2>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a1">
    <a2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a2>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b1">
    <b2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </b2>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of the XSLT identity template, which is not needed in your particular example, as you are renaming all elements, but would be used if you did want to keep some elements the same.

Comment: Well, this is practically the same as the second thing I said I would rather avoid... I appreciate the effort and your approach does work, but needing 4 lines per element is just too much. Like I said to Martin Honnen, I will tackle this problem on a different level. I'll make the input tag names match those I need in the output, so I can make full use of the identity template.

Comment: Is your question about avoiding empty elements, or actually about how to rename lots of elements in a generic way? If you are really trying to change a '1' to a '2' at the end of each element name then it may be possible to have a generic template that does this, rather than specify separate ones for `a1` , `b1` etc. Alternatively, you can specify a separate XML file where names could be mapped, such as `<map><a1 newname='a2' /><b1 newname='b2' /></map>` and use that to rename elements.

Comment: actually the underlying problem is indeed about renaming lots of elements. I've read about the approach you suggest for that somewhere else too, and I agree it is a decent solution. Unfortunately, the map I'm making is for use in Microsoft BizTalk Server, which, despite data transformation being a core feature, has crappy support for XSLT. It's restricted to version 1.0 and such sorcery as using other XMLs in XSLT to map element names seems to be out of the question.