# How do I remove all the empty tags at the end of a list using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a set of paragraphs:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p/>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p/>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<p/>
<p/>
<p/>
```

What I want is remove the empty paragraphs at the end of the set of tags, but I want to keep the other empty tags.

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p/>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p/>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
```

I found answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706202/xslt-how-to-exclude-empty-elements-from-my-result) which explain how to remove all empty tags (or any type of tags, if that matter) but I'm not too sure how to remove just the last set of empty tags in a list like this.

At this point the document is expected to only include `<p>` elements. I can place them in any other tag, I use `<html><body>` as the parent tags.

Comment: Can you show us the parent element of the `p` elements and explain whether that parent will only contain only `p` elements or whether those `p` element can be mixed with or preceded or followed by other elements? If there are no other siblings then `<xsl:template match="p[not(node()) and not(following-sibling::p[node()])]"/>` should do.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I added info to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only `p` elements as siblings then you can use `<xsl:template match="p[not(node()) and not(following-sibling::p[node()])]"/>` with the identity transformation template:

http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMW/1 shows the complete stylesheet with

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[not(node()) and not(following-sibling::p[node()])]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Nice xpath, plus one.